# Error Handling in OkHttp

Tags: android, okhttp

I have been usually using volley for my network request due to it's easy implementation of error handling and also for it's network imageview, but now I would want to try to use OkHttp.

I have been able to detect if there is a response from a URL, but how would I be able to detect for example if the request failed in terms of (No internet Connection, Request Timed Out, URL cannot be reached)?

I know the code is kind of bare bones, I apologize for that.

This is my code:

```
 public void MakeCall() {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            call.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "RESPONSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or insight on how to do it! :D

Answer (score 0):

In your onFailure() you will get No internet Connection, Request Timed Out, URL cannot be reached callbacks via `IOException e`

You can set connection timeout and read timeout manually like this.

```
client.setConnectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // connect timeout
client.setReadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    // socket timeout
```